# What type of ViewController is this? UITabBarViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm making a menu screen for my sports app and decided on doing something like this:

[image: screenshot]

However, I'm not sure how this was created. It kind of works like a UITabBar, but when you click on it, a new viewController appears embedded in a viewController, and the tabBarController at the bottom has disappeared. That leads me to believe it's not a type of UITabBarController. Also, you can scroll through it and there is about 8 different buttons.

Comment: It could be anything

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a `UICollectionView` that pushes other view controllers onto the parent `UINavigationController`. There's a number of open source examples of this you can [find](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar) [on](https://github.com/jasarien/JSScrollableTabBar) [github](https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar).

Comment: Ah. So it's a parent VC with a child VC, not a split VC?

Comment: It's most likely not a split view controller because those aren't available before iOS8 on the iPhone and the looking at the navigation bar it looks like this app hasn't been updated since iOS6.

Comment: If the tab bar doesn't remain on screen when you select the different menu items it probably means that the whole view controller is replaced. It could be adding child view controllers but it would make more sense to me push new view controllers onto the navigation stack so you can pop them using the same back button.

Comment: What exactly should I search for on github to find more of those open source examples? And thank you for linking them.

Comment: I just searched for "tab bar" on CocoaControls: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tab+bar.